# Why is a comma needed before the following like simile?

Tags: punctuation

> It looked weird, like having a garden inside your apartment.

I thought the comma was optional in cases like these. But I searched for "it looked weird, like" on Google and almost every result had a comma.

Why is this? Is the comma really optional in cases like these?

Comment: You said, "almost every result had a comma." That implies some _didn't_ use a comma – so why would you think the comma wasn't optional?

Comment: The comma is "optional" but, in this case, "natural".  If you were saying this sentence out loud you would naturally put a pause after *weird* so the listener could better understand what you were trying to say.  The comma mimics this natural pause in the conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma *wouldn't* necessarily be included in a context like...

> *Many top footballers can bend it like Beckham*

In that example, the "comma-less" version would naturally be understood to mean *Many top footballers can bend the ball **the way Beckham can***. But if the comma *was* included, it would normally be understood as *Many top footballers can bend the ball. **Beckham is an example** of a player who can do this* (more accurately, perhaps, ***...an example of those top players***).

---

It would be quirky in the extreme to omit the comma in OP's specific example, but the important point to note is that just about ***the ONLY reason for having a comma is to reflect a pause in speech***.

Getting technical, OP's adverbial clause *like having a garden inside your apartment* is more naturally parsed as a [***sentence adverb***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/sentence-adverbs). That's why there's a pause before it, to reflect the fact that preceding *It looked weird* is being "separated out" as a "sentence" for the syntactic purpose here.